# Submit a form then reload the origin web page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an HTML form that submits in a new tab, but when it's submitted I need to reload my origin page, I tried this :

```
function view_message(element){
    window.location.reload();
    setTimeout(function(){
        element.submit();
    }, 100);        
}
```

But when I'm on the new tab, the origin page doesn't reload, I tried without the timeout, the page reloads but the form doesn't submit. Any idea?

Comment: When you reload the page, all scripts on the page stop, so `setTimeout()` doesn't work.

Comment: Try doing the reload *after* submitting. Normally the submit will cancel everything after, but if it's submitting to a new tab that might work.

Comment: try to call reload & submit inside setTimeout so both functions call at the same time.

Comment: @Barmar — "Try doing the reload after submitting" — That's what they are doing!

Comment: @AbhijeetKale — (a) You can't call two functions at the same time. That would just result in one being called immediately after the other instead of 100ms after the other. (b) You can't cause the browser to navigate the viewport to two different URLs at the same time.

Comment: @Quentin No, he's doing reload first, then submitting.

Comment: @Barmar — That's even weirder. Either way round, it won't work for the same reason.

Comment: @Quentin Not if you submit a form with `target="_blank"` to do the submission in another tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.opener.location.reload()` to reload the parent tab from which the form has been opened.